# WPF Show each image x seconds how?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, image

I'm trying to make a slideshow with a mediaElement that shows each image in listbox x seconds.

How do I make my code play each image x seconds before continuing?

This code adds all images to a listbox named Listbox1

```
    Dictionary<string, string> Listbox1Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Listbox1.Items.Clear();
        FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderDialog.SelectedPath = "C:\\";

        DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.ToString() == "OK")
            FileNameTextBox.Text = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
        string directory = FileNameTextBox.Text;
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".ini"));
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Listbox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
            Listbox1Dict.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), file);
        }
    }
```

This code shows all images in fullscreen but it skips everyone to last image at start.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var selected in Listbox1.Items)
        {
            string s = selected.ToString();
            if (Listbox1Dict.ContainsKey(s))
            {
                mediaElement1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                SearchBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                FileNameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(Listbox1Dict[s]);
                mediaElement1.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
                mediaElement1.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
                this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }

    }
}
```

Tried this code to make the image play one by one but I get an error. Look on comment on code:

```
private int currentSongIndex = -1;

void mediaElement1next(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(currentSongIndex == -1)
    {
        currentSongIndex = Listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
    currentSongIndex++;
    if(currentSongIndex < Listbox1.Items.Count)
    {
        mediaElement1.Play(Listbox1.Items[currentSongIndex]); // No overload for method 'Play' takes 1 arguments    
    }
    else
    {
        // last song in listbox has been played
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to introduce a pause there somewhere. Maybe using `AutoResetEvent` would help, possibly maybe somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your image paths in a list & use the tick event of a timer.
Something like:

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = getNextImage();
}

private string getNextImage()
{
    //code...
}
enter code here
```

EDIT:
Add a class variable: int index = 0;
On the SearchBtn_Click event, add the results to the list.

```
//..
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        paths.Add(file);
    }
//..
```

Then do as I did above and the content of the getNextImage method would be:

```
private string getNextImage()
{
    if(index < paths.Count - 1)
    {
        index += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    return paths[index];   
}
```

Comment: hm can't make the code work... Can you write an example by the code that I provided please?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, But i'm using WPF and no picturebox is existst there.
I'm using mediaelement.
Any idea for that one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a timer to set your next image. Using the code you're currently using, it will iterate through your list and change the image until you get to the end.

Take a look at [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). You could set it so, at each tick, it would change to the next image. Something like this (just writing off my head)

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
```

Then, inside your eventhandler:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the next image
}
```

Of course you can use other kinds of timers, but that's the main idea.

Comment: Instead of a foreach, have an index `n` and increment it every time the timer ticks. Then, to get your image, you get the `nth` element of the listbox instead of iterating through it.

Comment: Updated my code, check my post again. So how do I take care of this issue? :/

Comment: Where did that play come from? I thought you just needed to change the `Source` of the image, just like you did up above.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to implement a thread that counted to X and then called a NextImage() function when done.

Comment: Yes that's what I have been thinking too but there has to be a "next image control" for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Listbox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                else
                {
                    curImage = 0;
                    dispatcherTimer.Start();
                }
            }
        }




private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        ShowNextImage();
    }, null);            
}



private void ShowNextImage()
{
    if (curImage >= Listbox1.Items.Count)
        curImage = 0;

    var selected = Listbox1.Items[curImage];
    string s = selected.ToString();
    if (Listbox1Dict.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        mediaElement1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        SearchBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Listbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        FileNameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(Listbox1Dict[s]);
        mediaElement1.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        mediaElement1.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

and declaration

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int x = 2; //seconds
        private int curImage = 0;
```

and some construct

```
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, x);
```